# Redhat Linux Kernel what does GA mean?

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel

When Redhat release a new major version such as 5.3, 5.4,5.5 .. the kernels seem to be referenced as GA , what does GA stand for ?

example in this info doc 
http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhelv5-announce/2009-January/msg00000.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[General Availability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#General_availability_.28GA.29) - i.e. stable and ready to use and be supported.

Comment: doh ! I thought thats what it meant